# Changing global variable value not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

i am having a problem in changing the value of my global variables in javascript...Here's the full code.

```
//Initialize cordoba
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    var undefined;
    var phone_number;

    //change phone_number
    checkData();

    //alert the new phone_number
    alert(phone_number);


    function checkData(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Demo", "1.0", "Demo", 512000);
        db.transaction(selectProfile,DBerror);
    }

    function selectProfile(db){
        db.executeSql('SELECT phone_number FROM profile', [],
            function(db,results){
                if(results.rows.length > 0){
                    //change the global variable(phone_number)
                    phone_number = results.rows.item(0).phone_number;
                }else{location.href = 'index.html';}
            },
            DBerror
        );
    }
}
```

In every page, i need to get the phone number value from the database, change the global variable (phone_number) to that value and use it through out the whole script.
Thanks

Comment: that one is aside, it's for checking if a variable exists and you must define that for old browsers

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply have a `getPhoneNumber()` function that returns the phone number? Then you could say `var phone_number = getPhoneNumber();`

Comment: It can't be implemented (or maybe i couldn't figure out a way to do it) because of how the phonegap api works

Answer (score 1):

Declare `phone_number` outside of any function should work.

You can also use `window.phone_number` to guarantee a global scope.  But this is considered bad practice?  I'm sure someone with much more experience than I can explain why.

Comment: `window.phone_number` is only bad practice inasmuch as global variables are generally bad practice. The only particular bad thing about using `window` is that your code will be marginally more difficult to port to node.js, which uses `global` instead of `window` as its global.

Comment: @Spikes You need to define `phone_number` outside of any variables **AND** *not* define it anywhere else. If you just added a `var phone_number` at the top of your script but *didn't remove* the `var phone_number` inside `onDeviceReady`, the inner declaration will "shadow" the outer declaration, so setting `phone_number` sets the local variable, rather than the global one.

Comment: @Spikes While my above comment is true, I just read your code more closely and see you're making a classic async mistake, which will also cause your code to fail. The callback in `db.executeSql` does not run until after the `alert` runs.

Comment: @apsillers; that must be it. I've searched the W3C for a solution but couldn't find any. Can you rewrite the code in a way that it works. I need to get the data from the database before anything even happens on the page. Thanks a lot

Comment: @apsillers; I've rewritten the code. Thanks for your suggestion, it really helped.